# Html 2 Text - Remove "hidden" Text

Tags: java, html

I am currently looking for ways to read the visible text of a website and store it into plaintext string using Java.

In other words, I'd like to convert something like this:

`Hello <span style="display: none">stupid</span> World` into "Hello World"

or something like

`<span>Un</span>friendly` into "Unfriendly" (and not something like "Un friendly")

or

```
Hello

World
```

into "Hello World" (as new lines are ignored in HTML)

Do you know of any lib capable of assisting in this task?

Cheers,

Matthias

Comment: What you need is some kind of HTML renderer.

Answer (score 4):

[Boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) is an HTML cleaning library written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra/getting-started.jsp) to see if the API provides any method to render the HTML and convert it into plain text.